# Looking for easy way to setup a callback url for a console program requesting an API

Tags: python, callback, azure-web-app-service

I am building a python program that send POST request to a 3rd party API. I am the only user and not building an App for others. I built the program on my Win11 desktop try to query (read only) data from 3rd party.

The problem is the API required 3-Legged OAuth. Based on my understanding, I need to setup a web server and pay for a domain in order to provide a valid Callback URL. Is it true?

Are there are better approaches for my case? I have Azure subscription. Could I setup a static web app for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "App registrations" > "New registration", After creation of the app registration then add your endpoints to it as shown in below.

[image]

- choose the supported account types, and set a redirect URI (you can use `http://localhost:5000/callback` for local testing).
- Once the registration is complete, note down the "Application (client) ID" and "Directory (tenant) ID" from the application overview.

[image]

**Implement OAuth Flow in Flask App**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session, jsonify
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "your_secret_key"

# Azure AD application details
client_id = "your_client_id"
client_secret = "your_client_secret"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id"

# 3rd party API details
api_url = "https://api.example.com/endpoint"

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Home Page"

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    auth_url = (
        f"{authority}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
        f"client_id={client_id}"
        "&response_type=code"
        "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/callback"
        "&scope=User.Read"  # Adjust scopes based on your API permissions
    )
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    if "code" in request.args:
        code = request.args["code"]
        cca = ConfidentialClientApplication(
            client_id, client_secret, authority,
            post_logout_redirect_uri="http://localhost:5000"
        )
        token_response = cca.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            code, scopes=["User.Read"], redirect_uri="http://localhost:5000/callback"
        )
        session["access_token"] = token_response["access_token"]
        return "Authentication successful! You can now make API requests."

    return "Authentication failed."

@app.route('/make_api_request')
def make_api_request():
    access_token = session.get("access_token")
    
    if access_token:
        # Make a sample API request using the obtained access token
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        try:
            # Replace this with the actual payload and endpoint of the 3rd party API
            api_data = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
            response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=api_data)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                return jsonify(response.json())
            else:
                return f"Error: {response.status_code}\nResponse: {response.text}"

        except Exception as e:
            return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
    else:
        return "Access token not found. Please authenticate first."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

The `/make_api_request` route uses the access token stored in the session to make a sample POST request to the 3rd party API (`api_url`)

- Run the Flask app & Visit `http://localhost:5000/login` in your browser to initiate the OAuth flow.
  -   After authentication, you'll be redirected to the callback URL, and the access token will be stored in the session.

[image]

Visit `http://localhost:5000/make_api_request` to make the API request using the obtained access token.

Comment: What will be the use of "Application (client) ID" and "Directory (tenant) ID" for the App registration?

Comment: @Mark `Application (client) ID` identifies your specific application, while the `Directory (tenant) ID` identifies the Azure AD tenant to which your application belongs. Together, these IDs help Azure AD manage and route authentication and authorization requests appropriately. For security reasons, the "Client Secret" (or other forms of client credentials) is used as a confidential piece of information for authenticating your application during the OAuth flow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to get the data from 3rd party API. However I need to press "accept" to authorize the request. That means I need to attend to the request. Any suggestion to make it unattended? I want to make it a daily routine.

Comment: I am not the global admin. So when I browse http://localhost:5000/login, it prompt a request to our Admin. I am not sure I do it right. Why requesting a 3rd party API require our Admin's approval?

Comment: If I need to call the SharePoint rest API using this App, what API Permission I need to grant to my app registration? Is "AllSites.Read" sufficient to query all items for a specific sharepoint list?